# RecycleView with data from JSONArray and the need to highlight the elements of the list: best practice

Tags: android, arrays

Good day.
I have an RecycleView list with data from JSONArray. Customer can select or de-select any item from this list by click on it.
So every RecycleView’s item can be in two states: marked (selected) or not.
How best to realize this opportunity? By creating a new separate array with additional “selected” boolean property and loading data into this array when creating a list as a RecycleView’s data source?
Or extend JSONArray with this property and use single data sourse (JSONArray)?

I have little programming experience under Android but see the following advantages and disadvantages:

- JSONArray unhandled so needs to use try/catch construction at all
  points of work with him;
- JSONArray more visible in the code due to named elements like jsonList.put("selected", "false");
- work with traditional java array must be faster;
- any changes in source JSONArray (in fact, with each new request to the server) needs to full recreation of this ‘buffer’ separate java array.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using separate array in adapter for holding item state. In my mind it more flexible when you not need to modify model and keep all logic inside adapter.

You can use different types depends on situation, not only traditional java arrays.

For example, mu solution to hold checked or not state for item in recyclerview:

Declare array to hold state:

```
SparseBooleanArray itemStateChecked= new SparseBooleanArray();
```

In onClick() put value for this item:

```
if (!itemStateChecked.get(item.id))
            itemStateChecked.put(item.id, true);
        else
            itemStateChecked.delete(item.id);
```

In onBindViewHolder() restore state:

```
if (itemStateChecked.get(1))
        mCheckView.setChecked(true);
    else
        mCheckView.setChecked(false);
```

SparseArray accept only primitive as key and SparseBooleanArray returns false if mapping not found.

Comment: Please provide some example to understand better.

Comment: Provided some example above